# Counting forum topics and replies

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: posts and forum_topics. Each post (a reply) is associated with another post (a forum topic, which is then associated with the forum_topics tables).

Problem: I need to count all forum topics and replies in the posts table. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT ForumTopic.id, ForumTopic.title, ForumTopic.modified, COUNT(ReplyLeftOuterJoin.id) as replies_count
FROM forum_topics AS ForumTopic
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts AS PostLeftOuterJoin
ON PostLeftOuterJoin.object_id = ForumTopic.id
    AND PostLeftOuterJoin.object_type = 'forum_topic'
    AND PostLeftOuterJoin.status = 'approved'
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts AS ReplyLeftOuterJoin
ON ReplyLeftOuterJoin.object_id = PostLeftOuterJoin.id
   AND ReplyLeftOuterJoin.object_type = 'post'
   AND ReplyLeftOuterJoin.status = 'approved'
WHERE ForumTopic.forum_category_id = 'some_id'
```

**Edit**

Currently I'm only getting a count of all replies associated with a forum_topic (post) in the posts table. I would like to get a count of forum_topics in posts table associated with a forum topic in the forum_topics table.

**NB** FYI, a solution to this problem should use one query only.

Here is the schema of the two tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `posts`;
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `context_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `context_type` enum('resource','module','kwik','user','assignment') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_private` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_unread` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `last_replied` datetime NOT NULL,
  `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `object_type` enum('forum_topic','forum','user','post') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('approved','unapproved','disabled') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `forum_topics`;
CREATE TABLE `forum_topics` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `view_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `forum_category_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: What do you see as a result of this query and what would you like to see?

Comment: See my edit above. I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ForumTopic.forum_category_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT PostLeftOuterJoin.id) as forumtopics_count,
    COUNT(ReplyLeftOuterJoin.id) as replies_count
FROM forum_topics AS ForumTopic
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts AS PostLeftOuterJoin
ON PostLeftOuterJoin.object_id = ForumTopic.id
    AND PostLeftOuterJoin.object_type = 'forum_topic'
    AND PostLeftOuterJoin.status = 'approved'
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts AS ReplyLeftOuterJoin
ON ReplyLeftOuterJoin.object_id = PostLeftOuterJoin.id
   AND ReplyLeftOuterJoin.object_type = 'post'
   AND ReplyLeftOuterJoin.status = 'approved'
WHERE ForumTopic.forum_category_id = 'some_id'
GROUP BY
    ForumTopic.forum_category_id
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the I'm getting a count of 0 for both `replies_count` and `forum_count` when I run the query against the db

Comment: Alright, thanks, now I understand better mand modified my answer query, can you have a look again?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can get the result in two queries

the following query will give you the count of posts in each forum

```
select f.id,f.title,f.modified,Type='Posts',Number=count(*) 
from forum_topics as f
inner join posts p on p.forumid=f.id --u used in your query PostLeftOuterJoin.id ( is this the forum id or the posts id ?)
where p.status='approved' and p.object_type='forum_topic'
group by f.id,f.title,f.modified
union
select f.id,f.title,f.modified,Type='Replies',Number=count(*) 
from forum_topics as f
inner join posts p on p.forumid=f.id --u used in your query PostLeftOuterJoin.id ( is this the forum id or the posts id ?)
where p.status='approved' and p.object_type='posts'
group by f.id,f.title,f.modified
```

to distinguish between the posts and replies, i added the Type

and from your application level you can get the forum post count when Type=Posts and same as for the replies

---

another method

```
select f.id,f.title,f.modified,Posts=(select count(*) from posts p where f.id=p.object_id and p.status='approved' and p.object_type='forum_topic'),
Replies=(select count(*) from posts p on where f.id=p.object_id
and p.status='approved' and p.object_type='posts')
from forum_topics f
where f.forum_category_id='someid'
```

hope that this will help you

regards

Comment: Sorry, man that `PostLeftOuterJoin.id` is actually `PostLeftOuterJoin.object_id` (silly, typo). `PostLeftOuterJoin.object_id` is the forum topic id which links a post to a forum_topic in the forum_topics table.

Comment: was the query helpful for you? if yes please mark the reply as answer

Comment: Splitting the query into two queries will force me to change the model i.e create another method to change the format of the data so that the view doesn't break. Unfortunately I don't have time to do that now.

Comment: i put another method that will calculate the number of posts and replies for each forum in the same query